# Расположить блоки в одну строку

Tags: css, html, display

```css
.colBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Надо расположить в одну строку */
}

.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.brown {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: brown;
}

.orange {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.black {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.white {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="bgColor">
  <div class="colBlock">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="brown"></div><br>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div><br>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="green"></div><br>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button class="closeButton" id="bgColClose" onclick="closeCondWind()">Закрыть</button>
</dialog>
```

Надо расположить эти блоки в одну строку , пробовал не выходит

Comment: пример почему не воспроизводится ? для родительского блока `display:flex;`

Comment: Нельзя менять `display` родительского элемета, потому что у `<dialog>` по умолчание `display:none` и если его поменять , то у меня будет этот блок будет показываться на странице без нажатия на кнопку

Comment: тогда для всех потомков float:left, я не про dialog говорю ..а о colblock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то так.

`.colBlock div::before` как фича :D

```css
.colBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Надо расположить в одну строку */
}

.red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.brown {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: brown;
}

.orange {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.black {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.yellow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.white {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

/* ----- */

.colBlock {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

.colBlock div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.colBlock div::before {
    content: attr(class);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgColor">
  <div class="colBlock">
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="brown"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button class="closeButton" id="bgColClose" onclick="closeCondWind()">Закрыть</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: И да, я б не стал использовать тег `<dialog>`, уж лучше `<div>` и js\jq.

Answer (score 3):

Один из вариантов `flex`. Еще существуют `grid`, можно даже `float` использовать....

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#bgColor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.colBlock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.brown {
  background: brown;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}

.grey {
  background: grey;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="bgColor" open>
  <div class="colBlock">
    <div class="line red">red</div>
    <div class="line blue">blue</div>
    <div class="line brown">brown</div><br>
    <div class="line orange">orange</div>
    <div class="line black">black</div>
    <div class="line grey">grey</div><br>
    <div class="line yellow">yellow</div>
    <div class="line white">white</div>
    <div class="line green">green</div><br>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button class="closeButton" id="bgColClose" onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').close()">Закрыть</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: а почему он не закрывается ?

Comment: Все прекрасно закрывается

Comment: ни чего там не закрывается

Comment: ты видать с мазилы пробуешь

Comment: ну да....с фокса ...гуглхром напичкали экспириментальными функциями из за чего теперь многие не могут отличить где правильно а где нет

Answer (score -1):

Этим всем блокам нужно дать display:inline-block. А не только родительскому.

Как-то так:

```
.colBlock > div {
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

Comment: А ещё `float: left;`, а ещё родителю `::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}`..